# Losing some flash() data in laravel

Tags: laravel, session

## Background

System:

- Laravel 10
- LAMP setup

When I log in to Laravel, there is no session data and hence the expected flash message is missing.

If I add a flash message to a controller to test the session it works as expected.

This works as expected (`DashboardController`):

```php
    public function index(Request $request): View
    {
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'Hello world');
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }
```

I've used the Breeze starter kit to create simple login pages.
This code does not work when I add a flash message and is as follows (AuthenticatedSessionController):

```php
    public function store(LoginRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('success', 'You have successfully logged in!');
    }
```

Note, unlike various other answers I am not using dd() or similar. This effect also happens on other controllers, such as `ConfirmablePasswordController`.

In the `kernel.php`, `StartSession::class` is in `$middlewareGroups['web']` and `$middlewarePriority` array.

### TL:DR

Why is my session flashing not working on Breeze controllers?

Thanks

[EDIT: I've repeated this with a clean install and the problem remains]

Comment: weird suggestion, but instead of intended, can you use route names instead? Since this is how I typically return flash message to my blade files. Btw, how do you display your flash message in your frontend?

Comment: how do you know the flash message isn't available after the redirect?

Comment: I have tried using route names. There's no change.
I know it's not available because I have a flash display that doesn't show, and a var_dump()  of session confirms it to be empty.

Comment: you are trying to use this session variable where? and where are you doing the `var_dump`?

Comment: In the view immediately after the redirect.

This could be: `return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)` OR `return redirect(route('dashboard'))`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so i’m posting an answer. I have had a similar issue. The flash massage was not displayed so i used the browser inspector tools and i saw an extra redirect losing the flashed message and that was my problem. Maybe check for extra redirects?